# Prove that three segments which intersect a circle pass through the same point

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

In a scalene triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $AB\ne AC$, I state we have $Y$ which is the point of intersection of the bisector of $\angle A$ with $BC$ and $D$ is the point where the perpendicular line from $A$ towards $BC$ intersects $BC$. If $E$ and $Z$ are the intersections of the circumcircle of $\triangle AYD$ with $CA$ and $AB$ respectively, prove that $AD, BE, CZ$ pass through the same point

[image]

I don't know how to solve this question. The first thing I thought of was maybe proving that their intersection is the orthocenter of the triangle or something like that, but that did not lead me to a solution. I then thought of using power of a point towards the circle, but that didn't work either. Could you please explain to me how to solve this question?

Comment: Have you tried Menelaus? Seems like the ratios can be easily obtained

Comment: I didn't even know about Menelaus before today, thank you so much @CalvinLin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The idea is to use Ceva, and we have to show that $ \frac{ BZ}{ZA} \times \frac{ AE } { EC } \times \frac{CD}{DB } = 1  $.
This can be done by side length chasing (either the lengths themselves, or the ratio of the lengths).

> $BZ = BY \cos \beta$ , $CE = CY \cos \gamma$.

> $\frac{BY}{CY} = \frac{AB} {AC} = \frac{\sin \gamma } {\sin \beta} $ , so $ \frac{BZ}{CE} = \frac{ \tan \gamma } { \tan \beta}  $

> $AZ = AY \cos \alpha/2 = AE$

> $\frac{DC}{BD} = \frac { AD / \tan \gamma}{ AD / \tan \beta } $

Comment: Isn't it Ceva what we want to show? Anyway, that's the way I would have solved the problem ;) [+1]

Comment: @Dr.Mathva and by applying intersecting secant theorem, the answer becomes simpler.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Oh gods yes lol. I often mix up the 2 names.

Answer (score 4):

By intersecting secant theorem,

$BZ \cdot BA = BD \cdot BY$
$CY \cdot CD = CE \cdot CA$

So we have, $BZ \cdot CD \cdot BA \cdot CY = BD \cdot CE \cdot CA \cdot BY$

But by angle bsector theorem we have, $BA \cdot CY = CA \cdot BY$

Also as $AY$ is angle bisector of $\angle EAZ$ and it is also the diameter of the circle, $AE = AZ (\triangle AZY \cong \triangle AEY$)

That leads to $BZ \cdot AE \cdot CD = BD \cdot CE \cdot AZ \ $ and hence by Ceva's theorem, Cevians $AD, BE$ and $CZ$ concur.

Comment: That was indeed very nice!!

Comment: Thank you @Dr.Mathva